# Output pictures consecutively?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have Python code which plots a figure using pyplot, then I close the figure and the next one appears, then I close and the next etc.

Is it possible in Python to have the output windows appear one after the other like a short animation?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8956211/302369