# dynamically plot the optimization result in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm doing a numerical optimization, and I want to visualize the `loss` of the objective function at each iteration, which means I need to add one point when each iteration is done into the plot.

I thought this might be a `matplotlib.animation` job, but it seems that `animation` just updates the plot by `interval` period of time, this is not what I want.

After searching SO, I indeed find a [tricky solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956211/888051), but is there a better way?

Comment: using the `set_*data` and `draw` methods isn't too complicated - does it not work for you? If you think that the more performant version is too complicated, you could always consider pyqtgraph.

Comment: @mdurant, that works for the `ax.plot` thing, but what about `ax.scatter`?

Answer (score 0):

To set the data of a scatter in-place, you need to do the following:

```
pc = ax.scatter( x, y, ...)
```

and modify:

```
px.set_offsets( xnew, ynew )
```

before invoking wither draw (slower) or the blit method you linked.