# More Efficient Alternatives to plt.draw() in MatPlotLib

Tags: python, performance, user-interface, matplotlib, interactive

I'm trying to make an interactive GUI using MatPlotLib, and the thing users notice most is the latency between, say, changing a slider, and the GUI responding.

Currently, I am using `plt.draw()` at the end of every event, which works well, except for the fact that it causes `256ms` of the function's `259ms` runtime.

In researching alternatives to `plt.draw()`, I came across this post: [why is plotting with Matplotlib so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955869/why-is-plotting-with-matplotlib-so-slow) , in which it was recommended to use `fig.canvas.blit(ax1.bbox)` as an alternative which reloads just the graph, and not the entire figure.
When I use this, the event handler runs in `3ms`, however the GUI updates during the following event, rather than at the end of the current event as if the event was caught in a buffer: `User input 1`>`pause`>`User input 2`>`GUI responds to input 1`>`pause`>`User input 3`>`GUI responds to input 2`, making the program unusable.

So what alternatives do I have?  Fixing either one of these problems would allow me to run a very fast GUI.  I'll post code if you need it.

Note 1:  When using `fig.canvas.blit(ax1.bbox)`, the sliders, buttons, etc will change immediately, and only the subplots will behave as described above.

Note 2: `fig.canvas.draw_idle()`, as used in the widgets example here http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html, and `fig.canvas.draw()`, perform identically to `plt.draw()`

Comment: If you are on Windows, are you using the latest matplotlib version? There was some kind of a bug that made the rendering slow under Windows (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2559/).

Comment: Unfortunately I am using MacOSX at the moment

Comment: I'd recommend using PyQtGraph instead. It uses C++ as its backend, so it's a lot faster than Matplotlib: https://nrecursions.blogspot.com/2019/09/realtime-plotting-in-python.html