# Python > Matplotlib > Animated live plot > framerate

Tags: python, matplotlib

this is my first question post.

**Im seeing a refresh rate of about 1 frame every 5 seconds in my live plot using the below code.  I want to see something close to real-time updates.  The serial rate of the data being plotted is sufficient to support at least 2 frames per second.**

I've built this simple script using examples i've found on this site, and read several questions pertaining to reapplication of those examples.

I am not a frequent/experienced coder.

```
import serial #import pyserial library

ser=serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem14611', baudrate = 9600, timeout=1) #set serial COM port, baud, [timeout if you are using a while loop]
my_list = []    # define a list to hold each data point as it comes in
count_list = [] # define a list to hold the x axis data point (in our case we will grab the computer time stamp of each data point)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #import the matplot library
import matplotlib.animation as animation #define the matplotlib animation function object
import time #import the python time library

fig = plt.figure() #define a figure object
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) #add a subplot to the figure, you can add more subplots for additional data types if desired

xar = [] #define a list to hold the new x dimension of plot on each update
yar = [] #define a list to hold the new y dimension of plot on each update

def animate(i): #define an animation function 

    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('ascii') #read current data on serial monitor, decode as ascii data type
    Data = arduinoData.split() #split each word/text block into a temporary list named Data
    if len(Data) > 2: #check if Data has at least 3 words/text blocks
        if Data[0]=='Yaw,': #check if position 0 in the temporary list Data is equal to "Yaw,"

            p=Data[3] #set variable p equal to position 3 of the list Data
            s = p.replace(',', '') #set variable s equal to variable p, after removing the comma
            yar.append(float(s))
            print(float(s))

            #millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000)) #grab current EPOCH time of loop from local pc  
            xtime = time.time()  
            xar.append(xtime)



    ax1.clear() #clear previous axis data
    ax1.plot(xar,yar) #plot updated axis data for xar and yar lists

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1) #call the animation function with an interval of ? millis
plt.show() #show plot in gui
```

Comment: I found the answer to my question @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/40749129