# Efficient way to update matplotlib figure in gui?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

My application is receiving data over the network at about 30fps, and needs to update a horizontal bar chart dynamically based on this new data.

I am using a matplotlib figure inside a tkinter window for this purpose. Profiling my code has shown that a major bottleneck in my code is the updating of this figure.

A simplified version of the code is given below:

```
    def update_bars(self):
        """
        Updates a horizontal bar chart
        """
        for bar, new_d in zip(self.bars, self.latest_data):
            bar.set_width(new_d)
        self.figure.draw()
```

The lag I am experiencing is significant, and grows quickly over time. Is there a more efficient way to update the matplotlib figure? Any help would be great.

EDIT: I will be looking at [this](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations) for possible speedup tips. I'll update if I get something working.

Comment: You may look at the following questions (a) [fast-live-plotting-in-matplotlib-pyplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126176/fast-live-plotting-in-matplotlib-pyplot) 
(b) [real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib) 
(c) [why-is-plotting-with-matplotlib-so-slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955869/why-is-plotting-with-matplotlib-so-slow)

Answer (score 1):

You can update the data of the plot objects. But to some extent, you can't change the shape of the plot, you can manually reset the x and y axis limits.

e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 6*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax.plot(x, y)

for phase in np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 500):
    line1.set_ydata(np.sin(x + phase))
    # render the figure
    # re-draw itself the next time 
    # some GUI backends add this to the GUI frameworks event loop.
    fig.canvas.draw() 
    fig.canvas.flush_events() # flush the GUI events
```

[flush_events](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase.flush_events)

> Flush the GUI events for the figure. Implemented only for backends
>   with GUIs.

**flush_events** make sure that the GUI framework has a chance to run its event loop and clear any GUI events.Sometimes this needs to be in a `try/except` block because the default implementation of this method is to raise `NotImplementedError`.

**draw** will render the figure,in the above code,maybe remove `draw` still work.But to some extent they're different.

Comment: I will try what you suggested, thanks btw. I am curious though, I see the call to draw(), wouldn't it be redundant to call flush_events() after that? (I am not much familiar with GUI development so forgive me if my question seems ignorant) EDIT: I just tried what you suggested, doesn't seem to make any difference :(