# How to overwrite a plot after pressing a button in pyplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have some csv files with data I want to plot. I want to use my arrow keys on my keyboard to overwrite the plot.

My Code:

```
import os, pandas, glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

counter = 0

class Plotter:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.plotter(filepath)

    def press(self, event):
        print('press', event.key)
        global counter
        if event.key == 'down':
            if (counter + 1) < len(files):
                counter = counter + 1
                self.plotter(files[counter])

        if event.key == 'up':
            if not (counter - 1) < 0:
                counter = counter - 1
                self.plotter(files[counter])

    def plotter(self, filepath):
        data = pandas.read_csv(filepath)
        fig = plt.figure()
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.press)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(data.x, data.y1, 'r-')

        ax2 = ax.twinx()
        ax2.plot(data.x, data.y2, '--')

        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    dir_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    files = list(glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, 'test*.csv')))
    print(files[counter])
    Plot = Plotter(files[counter])
```

My issue is: When I press the button a new window opens instead of overwriting the plot.

Any suggestions?

[EDIT](I want to keep the previous code, as the error is different with this approach) My Code after the comment from DavidG looks like:

```
import os, pandas, glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

counter = 0

class Plotter:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.press)
        self.plotter(filepath)

    def press(self, event):
        print('press', event.key)
        global counter
        if event.key == 'down':
            if (counter + 1) < len(files):
                counter = counter + 1
                self.plotter(files[counter])

        if event.key == 'up':
            if not (counter - 1) < 0:
                counter = counter - 1
                self.plotter(files[counter])

    def plotter(self, filepath):
        data = pandas.read_csv(filepath)

        ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(data.x, data.y1, 'r-')

        ax2 = ax.twinx()
        ax2.plot(data.x, data.y2, '--')

        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    dir_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    files = list(glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, 'test*.csv')))
    print(files[counter])
    Plot = Plotter(files[counter])
```

Here nothing happens when I press down or up.

Comment: On each call to `plotter` you create a new figure with `fig = plt.figure()`. You probably want to create one figure with subplots and then keep updating that figure

Comment: I added an other approach, where I create a new figure only once. This time nothing happens, when I press a button.

Comment: use `plt.savefig('single_image.png')`?

Answer (score 0):

I put together a simplified version of your code that will draw random lines when a button is pressed up or down.  You don't need to re-define ax object each time, you need to clear it, it also seems necessary on my build to flush (if you are using a GUI)- ([Efficient way to update matplotlib figure in gui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872142/efficient-way-to-update-matplotlib-figure-in-gui)-) and redraw the canvas upon modifying the axes object (see comments in code).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

class Plotter:
    def __init__(self, fig, ax):
        self.fig = fig
        self.ax = ax
        self.plotter(ax)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.press)

    def press(self, event):
        print('press', event.key)
        if event.key == 'down':
            self.plotter(self.ax)
            # flush and redraw
            fig.canvas.flush_events()
            fig.canvas.draw()

        if event.key == 'up':
            self.plotter(self.ax)
            # flush and redraw
            fig.canvas.flush_events()
            fig.canvas.draw()

    def plotter(self, ax):

        x1 = np.random.choice(range(0,5), 2)
        y1 = np.random.choice(range(0,5), 2)
        print x1, y1
        # clear the ax and use new data
        ax.clear()
        ax.plot(x1, y1, 'r-')


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
Plot = Plotter(fig, ax)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `plt.show()` more than once. Create your **complete** plot in the init method and show it. Only update the plot in the `plotter` method.

```
class Plotter:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax2 = ax.twinx()
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.press)
        self.plotter(filepath)
        plt.show()

    def plotter(self, filepath):
        data = pandas.read_csv(filepath)
        self.ax.plot(data.x, data.y1, 'r-')
        self.ax2.plot(data.x, data.y2, '--')
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
```

Or even better create the plots themselves in the init method as well, only update them with new data.

```
class Plotter:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax2 = ax.twinx()
        self.line1, = self.ax.plot([], [], 'r-')
        self.line2, = self.ax2.plot([], [], '--')
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.press)
        self.plotter(filepath)
        plt.show()

    def plotter(self, filepath):
        data = pandas.read_csv(filepath)
        self.line1.set_data(data.x, data.y1)
        self.line2.set_data(data.x, data.y2)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by simply adding a plt.draw() at the end of my plotter function.

So the Code looks like:

```
import os, pandas, glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

counter = 0

class Plotter:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.press)
        self.plotter(filepath)
        plt.show()

    def press(self, event):
        print('press', event.key)
        global counter
        if event.key == 'down':
            if (counter + 1) < len(files):
                counter = counter + 1
                self.plotter(files[counter])

        if event.key == 'up':
            if not (counter - 1) < 0:
                counter = counter - 1
                self.plotter(files[counter])

    def plotter(self, filepath):
        data = pandas.read_csv(filepath)
        print(files[counter])
        plt.clf()
        ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(data.x, data.y1, 'r-')

        ax2 = ax.twinx()
        ax2.plot(data.x, data.y2, '--')
        fname = os.path.split(filepath)[1]
        ax.set_title(fname)
        plt.draw()
        plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    dir_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    files = list(glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, 'test*.csv')))
    print(files[counter])
    Plot = Plotter(files[counter])
```

This should be basically the same code like in my second code snippet. Just with added plt.draw()